# Using variable Names in For Loop (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I have two sets of directories. In the first directory, I have 8 files as such:

```
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ... file8.txt
```

In the second directory called `output`, I have multiple subdirectories. I want to write for loop that goes into each sub-directory inside `output` (so they are `directory1`, `directory2` etc...) and reads a file called `database_file_#.txt`. Currently, I have written this loop below, but it only works for one directory at a time.

```
for file in *; do 
name="${file%%.*}"
python script.py --parameter $file --out ../../output/directory1/${cts_name} 
--readin ../../output/directory1/database_file_1.txt 
done
```

For the second directory, I do the following:

```
 for file in *; do 
name="${file%%.*}"
python script.py --parameter $file --out ../../output/directory1/${cts_name} 
--readin ../../output/directory2/database_file_2.txt 
done
```

I do not want to keep re-writing directory# for all the directories inside output. Is there a way I can use a variable instead?

Comment: Write a function that takes the number as an argument.  Call it 8 times.

Comment: What does this question actually have to do with "using variable names"?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do 
  for file in *; do 
    name="${file%%.*}"
    python script.py --parameter "$file" --out ../../output/directory"${i}/${cts_name}" \
        --readin "../../output/directory${i}/database_file_${i}.txt" 
  done
done
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, I guess that's more reasonable. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the key variable here is "#", not "file".

SUGGESTION:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do 
  filename=file$i.txt
  outdir=../../output/directory$i
  python script.py --parameter $filename --out $outdir/${cts_name} --readin $outdir/database_file_$i.txt 
done
```

PS: This assumes there's a 1::1 relationship between input file and #.

Otherwise, if there are N files for every #, you'll need a nested loop.

In any case, keep it as SIMPLE as possible ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)).

Comment: Need more quotes if you don't want surprising/unexpected/undefined behavior here. `--parameter "$filename" --out "$outdir/$cts_name" --readin "$outdir/database_file_$i.txt"`, f/e. The POSIX shell language family is a bit unfortunate insofar as what *looks* simple (in terms of minimizing the amount of syntax) and what *is* simple (in terms of minimizing the amount of undesired runtime behavior) are often very different.

Answer (score 0):

On a first attempt you can try this (but continue reading):

```
for f in $(ls -R); do
  if [[ $f =~ database_file_+([0-9])\.txt ]]; then
    python script.py ... --readin "$f"
  fi
done
```

Where `+([0-9])` matches one or more numbers

Thanks to **Charles Duffy** comment, this snippet is much more accurate:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*/database_file_[0-9]+\.txt$" -exec python script.py ... --readin {} \;
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- one can do the same search much more robustly with `find`, without having undefined behavior in the presence of filenames with nonprintable characters. (Also, not all versions of `ls -R` emit fully-qualified paths -- some will emit `dirname:` and then `file`, not `dirname/file`, making that output utterly useless if you need the actual path to the file that was found)

Comment: In addition to the comment by Charles Duffy, your regex is incorrect.
You may want to say `database_file_[0-9]+\.txt` instead.
Another correction is you should enclose `$f` with double quotes.

Comment: @tshiono you can omit the double quotes for `$f` within double brackets  because of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748

Comment: Note too that `=~` enables ERE syntax (where matching one-or-more digits looks like `[[:digit:]]+`), not extglob syntax. It would be `[[ $f = ... ]]` for `...` to be parsed as a glob.